# HashMap with ArrayList key can not find it when Arraylist grows

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, hashcode

Well my problem is that in some part of my code I use an arraylist as a key in a hashmap for example

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And then I put my array like a key in a hash map (I need it in this way I'm sure of that)

```
HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, String> map = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, String>();
map.put(array, "value1");
```

Here comes the problem: When I add some value to my array and then I try to recover the data using the same array then the hash map cant find it.

```
array.add(23);
String value = map.get(array);
```

At this time value is null instead of string "value1"
I was testing and I discovered that the hashCode changes when array list grows up and this is the central point of my problem, but I want to know how can I fix this.

Comment: I'm almost certain you would *not* want to do that. It's more likely you would want a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`

Comment: Thank you very much for answering but I'm pretty sure I need it in this way...

Answer (score 3):

Use an `IdentityHashMap`. Then that same array instance will always map to the same value, no matter how its contents (and therefore hash code) are changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a mutable object (that is, one whose `hashCode` changes) as the key of a `HashMap`. See if you can find something else to use as the key instead. It's somewhat unusual to map a collection to a string; the other way around is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

Its a weird use case but if you must do it then you can sub class the array and override the hashCode method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain you would not want to do that. It's more likely you would want a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`. However, if you absolutely *must* do this, use a holder class:

```
public class ListHolder {
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public List<Integer> getList() {return list;}
}

Map<ListHolder, String> map = new HashMap<ListHolder, String>;
```

Comment: This doesn't really work - you cannot create an array of generic objects. The holder class would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of an add thing to try and do in my opinion.

I assume what you are trying to model is a variable length key made up of *n* integers, and assume that the hash of the `ArrayList` will be consistent, but I'm not sure that is the case.

I would suggest that you either subclass `ArrayList` and override the `hash()` & `equals()` methods, or wrap the `HashMap` in a key class.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reason: When we use HashMap.put(k, v), it will digit k.hashCode() so that it can know where to put it.

And it also find the value by this number(k.hashCode());

You can see the ArrayList.hashCode() function and it is in the abstract class of AbstractList. Obviously, after we add some object, it will change the haseCode value. So we can not find the value use HashMap.get(K) and there is no element which hashCode is K.

```
public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 1;
    for (E e : this)
        hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode());
    return hashCode;
}
```